# Python / Django fails at decoding file encoded as base64 by javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, base64

I'm using this, in react, to base64 encode an image file:

```
  fileToBase64 = (filename, filepath) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      var file = new File([filename], filepath);
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(event) {
        resolve(event.target.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  };
```

Which gets called by this:

```
  handleChangeFile = event => {
    const { name, files } = event.target;
    if (files.length) {
      const file = files[0];
      let fields = this.state.fields;
      this.fileToBase64(file).then(result => {
        fields[name].value = result;
      });
      fields[name].isFilled = true;

      this.setState({
        fields: fields
      });
    }
  };
```

And the whole fields variable gets posted to a django server, no issues so far.

On the python django end:

```
str_encoded = request.data["file"]
str_decoded = base64.b64decode(str_encoded)
```

The second line returns an error that `binascii.Error: Invalid base64-encoded string: length cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4`. I've googled and read that this is probably a padding issue, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: make sure the prefix code in js base64 string is removed before having this same string processed in python. Sth like that is the problem

Comment: @NikosM. It starts with this: data:application/octet-stream;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJR. So I need to remove up to and including base64,?

Comment: yes I think this is the problem

Comment: including the slash as well

Comment: @NikosM. and the /9j/?

Comment: hmm I'm not sure in php I strip the prefix if it starts with `data:` up to the position of `;` (semicolon) plus 8 characters. But i dont remeber right now why I did this, what I was trying to strip. But certainly this is the problem

Comment: Ok, I'll play around with it. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to strip the `base64` string from the prefix added by `javascript`.
The prefix is sth like `data:{type};base64,{actual-base64-string-follows}`

In php, where I had same issue, I tested if string starts with `"data:"` prefix and I strip it from start of string up to the position of the `;` (semicolon) plus 8 characters (to catch the final ";base64,").

Then you can use python to decode the `base64` string remaining as it is now a valid `base64` string.